# Rust Alpha and Old_IO

Tags: networking, rust, alpha, beta

I've been looking into learning Rust because it seems like a cool upcoming language but I have some concerns with Alpha apparently being feature complete and the std library network code all being in 'old_io'.

I've been wanting to do a small MUD from a book for awhile now and I thought the two would go hand in hand.

My question is this, has the net code moved and I can't find it, are they not replacing the old_io to something else or is a new IO just coming in and I am an idiot for not seeing it?

I'll go ahead with it regardless, I just can't find the answer.

Comment: I guess you should delete this question in a few days since it is now outdated and won't help anyone that gets a nightly from now on

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The new `io` module is being implemented right now in https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/21835

You can use `old_io` until then, but expect it to be removed soon. Once removed, moving to the new `io` will be a breaking change.

Comment: And a day after I ask, the new nightly has been released without old_io. Thanks for letting me know Ker!